# dart: HTTPRequest does not work in JS but in Dartium only

Tags: javascript, httprequest, dart

The following code works in Dartium, but not when converted to JavaScript in a browser:

```
import 'dart:html';

var getReq = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/programming-languages";

void main() {
  HttpRequest.getString(getReq).then((results) {
    query("#text").text = results;
  }).catchError((e) {
    print("Oops! Encountered $e");
  });
}
```

The error returned is:

```
ERROR: Instance of 'Interceptor'
```

I'm following the [JSON Web Service](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/) tutorial, the git repo for the complete source is [dartlang_json_webservice](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartlang_json_webservice_article_code).

I'm using Dart SDK version 0.7.2.1_r27268.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the server is returning a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header which is not working:

```
/**
 * Add Cross-site headers to enable accessing this server from pages
 * not served by this server
 * 
 * See: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ 
 * and http://enable-cors.org/server.html
 */
void addCorsHeaders(HttpResponse res) {
  res.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*, ");
  res.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
  res.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
}
```

Replacing:

```
res.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*, ");
```

with:

```
res.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

works. See [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) for futher information.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me both in Dartium and Chrome.

However, I get precisely the same error when I turn off the server.
I checked the console in chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/programming-languages. 
Origin http://127.0.0.1:3030 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. 
testhttpreq.html:1 Oops! Encountered Instance of 'Interceptor'
```

This is error similar to what you receive if you run this program in dart

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:8080/programming-languages. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3030' is therefore not allowed access.
Oops! Encountered Instance of 'HttpRequestProgressEvent'
```

with the generated toString in JavaScript (receiver being HttpRequestProgressEvent):

```
$.toString$0 = function(receiver) {
 return $.getInterceptor(receiver).toString$0(receiver);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The problem is not the stopped server, but the CORS header which is wrong in the tutorial sources. See below